# can i add sql query to OnepageController

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to add new field on OnepageController page , the field is when to ship your order and i want to store it as value on Database 
whats the mysql code to do this ? 
since my database name : mage_2015
table name : shipping date 
column name is : dateofShip

and the value of the is $dateship 
regards

Comment: You are asking the wrong question for your problem. In Magento you shouldn't (and shouldn't need to) add plain SQL queries anywhere. You can achieve this with an additional quote attribute.

Comment: i got field add on onestepcheckout page  all what i want is direct sql to add the value $dateship to table in db i created

Comment: You add an attribute and get it from a Magento collection. Direct SQL queries and Magento = future disaster.

Comment: iknow really what im doing since this website is privet and only can accessed by group of people work in the same building , so still need the direct SQL