# Magento and direct sql

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, controllers, sql

I want to add new field on `OnepageController` page , the field for something I want to add  and I want to store it as value in Database table.

What is the mysql code to do this ?

Since my database name is : `mage_2015`

Table name : `exam`

Column name is : `mag_info`

and the value of the is `$info`
regards

ps : I know what I am doing so direct `SQL` not dangerous for my use. Because my project is only accessible for few peoples.

Comment: Please do not ask literally the same question again if [it got closed](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93055/can-i-add-sql-query-to-onepagecontroller) the first time.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $connectionresource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
  $connectionWrite = $connectionresource->getConnection('core_write');

  $info = 'your value';

  $query = "insert into exam "
         . "(mag_info) values "
         . "(:mag_info)";

  $binds = array(
    'mag_info'    => $info
  );

  $connectionWrite->query($query, $binds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$examTable = $resource->getTableName('exam');
$resourceWrite = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$query = "INSERT INTO {$examTable} (`id`, `mag_info`) VALUES (NULL, 'Test');";
$resourceWrite->query($query);
```

**Note** : If table extra columns then need to add in query. Suppose i added "`id`" to primary key

Answer (score 0):

Direct query in databse for magento is not good way but if you want it create one file on root of magento and place below code change value of your filed as needed.

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");

Mage::app();

$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

$mageInfo = "value here";

$query = "insert into exam (mag_info) values (:mag_info)";

$binds = array('mag_info'=>$mageInfo);

$write->query($query, $binds);
```

Comment: syntex error !  i dont know what the problem is ?